# How to find difference.

Tags: derivatives

If $H:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is convex.

Let $H(p)=\frac{1}{r}|p|^r$ where $|p|=\sqrt{p_1^2+..+p_n^2}$  and $1<r<\infty$.

I need to find $\nabla_pH$ but i confuse  where $|p|$.

Please help for detail.

Comment: Here $H(p)$ is a function of $n$ variables, so the notation $H'(p)$ has no meaning.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa $H'$ is frequently used to indicate the total derivative. In the case of a scalar valued mapping it is the gradient.

Comment: so sorry, i lack of de.tail

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\nabla_p=\frac {\partial }{\partial p_1}\vec e_1+\frac {\partial }{\partial p_2}\vec e_2+\frac {\partial }{\partial p_3}\vec e_3+\ldots +\frac {\partial }{\partial p_n}\vec e_n$ and $|p|^r=(p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2+\ldots p_n^2)^{r/2}$.  Just take the partials in the usual manner.